# How to track when a Radio button is clicked in Google Tag Manager without clicking the submit button/moving on from the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-tag-manager

I've a pretty simple question but its been bothering me for a few days now. I want to track when someone clicks a radio button as a trigger or click, essentially to track the click and pull the data I need even if they haven't clicked submit or moved off the page. I just want to be able to do it when its clicked on the page but I can't seem to get my head around it in Google Tag Manager.

I ended up coming up with this so far but its pulling all clicks.

My solution was to create a custom variable that isolates the radio button by its class using Query Selector, then create a tag that fires on all clicks. The issue is that this is bringing back way more data than I need. It is bringing back random clicks on the page.

I tried to set it up in google tag manager as Some clicks, then set it to My Radio Variable - Equals - True but this didn't bring back anything at all.

My Radio Variable:

```js
function () {
   return document.querySelector('[class="radios__input"]:checked').id
}
```

I'm still new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might require not only the variable.

Now you can get the id from the radio element which is great.

But you said it is returning a lot of other element you don't need so looks like it is lack of the trigger setting.

`Trigger` should be the important one in this scenario.
You can narrow down the range to only the radio element you want to track.

Like configure the trigger to

`Click Element` , `match css selector` , `{Your special css selector to the radio button}`

---

If you are not familiar about the above I mentioned. You can attach some screenshots about what is your trigger and variable and how you use it in your GTM.